# Why future sequence runs this way?

Tags: dart, asynchronous, sequence, future

Following code:

```dart
void main() async {
  print("A");
  await Future(() async { // Main future
    print("B");
    Future(()=>print("C"));
    Future.microtask(()=>print("D"));
    await Future(()=>print("E"));
    print("F");
  });
  print("G");
}
```

shows this sequence:
`A B D C E F G`

I'm expecting this sequence:
`A B E F D C G`

Explaning:

1. dart prints `A`, correct
2. in Future dart prints `B`, correct
3. print("C") goes to EventQueue, we are still in Main Future Event completing in EventLoop
4. print("D") goes to MicrotaskQueue, we are still in Main Future Event completing in EventLoop
5. print("E") prints `E`, we still need to await Main Future Event in EventLoop
6. print("F") prints `F`
7. Main Future completed, going to MicrotaskQueue and taking microtask, printing `D`
8. Next Event in EventQueue is print `C`
9. completing with print with `G`

Where is my mistake? Flutter can interrupt Event completing and send it back to Event queue? Why D and C completes before E?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of interest is only the body:

```dart
Future(()=>print("C"));
Future.microtask(()=>print("D"));
await Future(()=>print("E"));
print("F");
```

You are expecting `E` and `F` to execute before `D` and `C` with the following explanation:

> 1. print("E") prints E, we still need to await Main Future Event in EventLoop
> 2. print("F") prints F
> 3. Main Future completed, going to MicrotaskQueue and taking microtask, printing D

> Flutter can interrupt Event completing and send it back to Event queue?

Your assumption here is that the "main future" should not be interrupted. **But the moment you use `await` in the main future, you return control back to the event loop.** At this point, the microtask queue consists of D, whereas the regular event queue consists of C and E, *in that order*.

Microtasks are executed first. So `D` is executed first.
Now the regular tasks are executed. `C` is executed.
Now `E` is executed. Control is transferred back to the "main future" which `await`ed `E`. The main future continues by `print`ing `F`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the complete description of what happens when and why:

```dart
void main() async {
  print("A");
  await Future(() async { // Main future
    print("B");
    Future(()=>print("C"));
    Future.microtask(()=>print("D"));
    await Future(()=>print("E"));
    print("F");
  });
  print("G");
}
```

- `main` is called by the event loop.
- `main` is `async` so this creates a future F0.
- `print("A")` runs and prints "A".
- `Future(() async { // Main future ... })` is evaluated
- This creates a new Future F1
- It starts a timer, T1, with duration zero to run the function.
- The `await` on F1 exits the `main` invocation, which returns F0.
- Control returns to the event loop.
- The timer T1 from above triggers the `Future()` constructor code as a new event.
- It runs function from above.
- It's an async function, so it creates a future F2.
- It prints "B".
- The `Future(() => print("C"))` creates a Future F3 and a zero-duration timer T2 to run `() => print("C")`.
- The `Future.microtask(...)` creates a Future F4 and schedules a microtask M1 to run `() => print("D")`.
- The `Future(()=>print("E"))` creates a Future F5 and zerp-duration timer T3 to run `() => print("E")`.
- The `await` on F5 exits the inner function which returns F2.
- The Future F1 gets completed with/linked to the Future F2, which hasn't completed yet.
- The microtask M1 triggers, running function printing "D". F4 is completed with `null`. Nobody listens.
- Microtask queue is empty
- Timer T2 triggers.
- This prints "C" and completes F3 with `null`. Nobody listens.
- Timer T3 triggers.
- Prints "E" and completes F5 with null.
- The await on F5 completes.
- Inner function prints "F".
- Inner function returns, completing F2 with `null`.
- This completes F1 with `null`.
- The `await` on F1 completes.
- `main` prints "G" and returns, completing F0 with `null`. Nobody listens.